# SVG Animation of rect and eclipse

Tags: animation, svg

Is it possible to animate this path one by one using svg animations (from top to bottom, linear or sth like that - including dots)? This code does not have paths.

This is my svg:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="495.303" height="422.699" viewBox="0 0 495.303 422.699">
  <g id="Group_110" data-name="Group 110" transform="translate(-670 -3225.301)">
    <rect id="Rectangle_172" data-name="Rectangle 172" width="244" height="1" transform="translate(961 3394) rotate(90)" fill="#57af2d"/>
    <rect id="Rectangle_173" data-name="Rectangle 173" width="269" height="1" transform="translate(691 3636.5)" fill="#57af2d"/>
    <ellipse id="Ellipse_289" data-name="Ellipse 289" cx="4" cy="4" rx="4" ry="4" transform="translate(964.303 3641.301) rotate(180)" fill="#57af2d"/>
    <circle id="Ellipse_298" data-name="Ellipse 298" cx="11.5" cy="11.5" r="11.5" transform="translate(670 3625)" fill="#57af2d"/>
    <rect id="Rectangle_174" data-name="Rectangle 174" width="202" height="1" transform="translate(960 3393)" fill="#57af2d"/>
    <ellipse id="Ellipse_291" data-name="Ellipse 291" cx="4" cy="4" rx="4" ry="4" transform="translate(964.303 3398.301) rotate(180)" fill="#57af2d"/>
    <ellipse id="Ellipse_292" data-name="Ellipse 292" cx="4" cy="4" rx="4" ry="4" transform="translate(1165.303 3398.301) rotate(180)" fill="#57af2d"/>
    <rect id="Rectangle_176" data-name="Rectangle 176" width="165" height="1" transform="translate(1162 3229) rotate(90)" fill="#57af2d"/>
    <ellipse id="Ellipse_294" data-name="Ellipse 294" cx="4" cy="4" rx="4" ry="4" transform="translate(1165.303 3233.301) rotate(180)" fill="#57af2d"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Animate how?  What sort of animation do you want?

Comment: From top to bottom, linear or sth like that (including dots)

Answer (score 3):

By far the best and simplest solution is to redraw your SVG so that it **does** use a `<path>` for the line.  That would be my recommendation.

If you cannot do that, then you can use a path in a mask to achieve what you want.  The path (in the mask) follows your line and when you animate its stroke, it reveals the real path.

```css
#revealer path {
  animation: reveal 3s linear forwards;
  stroke-dashoffset: 906px;
}

@keyframes reveal {
  from { stroke-dashoffset: 906px; }
  to   { stroke-dashoffset: 0px; }
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="495.303" height="422.699" viewBox="0 0 495.303 422.699">
  <defs>
    <mask id="revealer">
      <path d="M 492,0 L 492,168 L 290,168 L 290,412 L 0,412" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="26" stroke-dasharray="906 906"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>

  <g mask="url(#revealer)">
  <g id="Group_110" data-name="Group 110" transform="translate(-670 -3225.301)">
    <rect id="Rectangle_172" data-name="Rectangle 172" width="244" height="1" transform="translate(961 3394) rotate(90)" fill="#57af2d"/>
    <rect id="Rectangle_173" data-name="Rectangle 173" width="269" height="1" transform="translate(691 3636.5)" fill="#57af2d"/>
    <ellipse id="Ellipse_289" data-name="Ellipse 289" cx="4" cy="4" rx="4" ry="4" transform="translate(964.303 3641.301) rotate(180)" fill="#57af2d"/>
    <circle id="Ellipse_298" data-name="Ellipse 298" cx="11.5" cy="11.5" r="11.5" transform="translate(670 3625)" fill="#57af2d"/>
    <rect id="Rectangle_174" data-name="Rectangle 174" width="202" height="1" transform="translate(960 3393)" fill="#57af2d"/>
    <ellipse id="Ellipse_291" data-name="Ellipse 291" cx="4" cy="4" rx="4" ry="4" transform="translate(964.303 3398.301) rotate(180)" fill="#57af2d"/>
    <ellipse id="Ellipse_292" data-name="Ellipse 292" cx="4" cy="4" rx="4" ry="4" transform="translate(1165.303 3398.301) rotate(180)" fill="#57af2d"/>
    <rect id="Rectangle_176" data-name="Rectangle 176" width="165" height="1" transform="translate(1162 3229) rotate(90)" fill="#57af2d"/>
    <ellipse id="Ellipse_294" data-name="Ellipse 294" cx="4" cy="4" rx="4" ry="4" transform="translate(1165.303 3233.301) rotate(180)" fill="#57af2d"/>
  </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Can you explain, how did you calculate all this values? 

     <path d="M 492,0 L 492,168 L 290,168 L 290,412 L 0,412" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="26" stroke-dasharray="906 906"/>

Comment: I manually created the path by hand. I started with the path outside the mask, so it was visible.  Then once I had found all five points, and checked that the stroke width covered all the circles, I moved the path into the mask.